# Flowtype array of object type does not allow extra properties

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I am having a strange error with flow.
I'm simply trying to have a function that accepts an array of objects with an `amount` property but I'm having errors when providing objects with more properties.

```
const sum = (items: Array<{amount: number}>) => {/* something */}

type Item = {
  amount: number,
  name: string
};

const list: Array<Item> = [];

sum(list);
```

This gives me the following errors:

```
10: const list: Array<Item> = [];
                      ^ property `name`. Property not found in
2: const sum = (items: Array<{amount: number}>) => {/* something */}
                             ^ object type
```

https://flow.org/try/#0FAYw9gdgzgLgBFArgWzgXjgCgJYwKbJQBccAggE7kCGAngDwDeVyYiEMJEKARnuQL4A+AJTpBcBgHoAVAjDI8MABbYIAczjTJ-YLpg0ADnjgBJfKgwNgcOM1btOPPgBprcCMzwlY5VWuD8ANy64NDwADbYsCQU1PRmBOIYANoAusHASMiYkbDCgUA

Comment: I think it's bug that should be reported. If I replace it with `$ReadOnlyArray<{amount: number}>` it works…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Similar to the issue described here: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1644

This is not allowed, because the declaration you have,

```
const sum = (items: Array<{amount: number}>) => {/* something */}
```

would allow

```
const sum = (items: Array<{amount: number}>) => {
    items.push({amount: 4});
};
```

which is totally valid given the declaration of `items`. The array passed to `sum` is a list of your `Item` type, which requires a `name`, which isn't set here.

As you mentioned, `$ReadOnlyArray` works, because it is read-only and can't have more items added to it. Alternatively you could drop the type definitions from `sum` entirely and let Flow infer them, or change `Array<{amount: number}>` to `Array<*>` so Flow knows it is an array, but will infer the type of the content. Another alternative (that you left in the comments) is

```
const sum = <T : {amount: number}>(items: Array<T>) => {/* something */}
```

which will set `T` to `Item` based on your call to `sum(list)`, with the restriction that it will accept any `T` that is an object with a numeric `amount` property.

This is probably the best option.

Comment: That's really interesting and makes sense! Any idea why the following works then ? `const sum = <T: {amount: number}>(items: Array<T>) => {/* something */}`

Comment: Oh yeah, that's another option them. In that case Flow will resolve `T` as `Item` so it will know the proper type inside `sum`.