# Flow: cant create react component that takes a generic or an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I am struggling to understand why flow doesn't want me to pase a concrete object type to a react component that may take a generic or ay object of one specific shape.
It complaints that the existing properties on the concrete object are missing on the expected object. But the type I'm passing it is meant to be inferred as the generic one.
I think the problem is that I'm passing an array of one type, while it expects an array of two possible types (even if I don't want to use the second type)
Here is a small reproduction:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const data: {mola: boolean}[] = [{mola: true}]

type Props<T:{}> = {
a: Array<T|{cool: boolean}>
}

const Test = <T:{}>({a}:Props<T>) => 
    <div>
       {a.map(
           (props) => props.cool ?'cool' : 'other'
        )}
    </div>

const w = () => { return <Test a={data||[{mola: false}]} /> }
```

This is the error flow gives me:

```
11: const w = () => { return <Test a={data||[{mola: false}]} /> }
                                      ^ Cannot create `Test` element because property `mola` 
is missing in object type [1] but exists in object type [2] in array element of property `a`. [prop-missing]

References:
6: a:  Array<T|{cool: boolean}>
               ^ [1]
3: const data: {mola: boolean}[] = [{mola: true}]
               ^ [2]
```

[And a Try flow repl](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxLZFICiAZvUhnAL5z1QQhwDkUqDLwBQwtBAB2heABMKKAFy4QEADaK4AIwhrUE1gG0AunAC8cAzhXqlMKPiSsjomAE8wSOAAUuYQgB4AFQUcVgA+M1xhDQBBKCgUVyCAHxxxNSVtXRR9MOFWUXEpeECkaUigkPCAChwUVgUfCD8gsIBKMwjhOB64fxlgADc83tG6gDoQFDBq7tH5uGqwX0IO0wjl5sJx9NU4AH5eXd44JV4IGAALJCgRBZ62gtH-AHoB4cLJcoB3SOq1iJ4AQwfBQCR9UrlFCmHBycjJZKWawaegoVTEJzsF4RVhAA)

EDIT: I added a bit more complex example to make more obvious how I want to use the type

Comment: From your typing, I guess you trying to say "Array of `{cool: ...}` or an array of objects

Answer (score 1):

The problem Flow is trying to prevent me from is very well explained on this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44155934/flowtype-array-of-object-type-does-not-allow-extra-properties)

Declaring that the lower component can take an array of a sum type enables that component to push values that fulfill one or the other, like this:

```
const Test = <T:{}>({a}:Props<T>) => {
    a.push({ cool: true })

    return (
    <div>
       {a.map(
           (props) => props.cool ?'cool' : 'other'
        )}
    </div>)
}
```

Inside the component it is not violating the type, because it is a sum type and it matches one of the types. However, the array that I'm passing down is of one type exclusively. Because of this, flow will not allow you tu pass down such array because there is the risk that it gets "perverted" inside the component.

However, if you declare the array as readOnly, you are guaranteed that nobody will push anything to your precious array, and then you can pass it down.

```
type Props<T:{}> = {
a: $ReadOnlyArray<T|{ +cool: boolean }>,
}
```

[Fixed example](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxLZFICiAZvUhnAL5z1QQhwDkUqDLwBQwtBAB2heABMKKAFy4QEADaK4AIwhrUE1gG0AunAC8cAzhXqlMKPiSsjomAE8wSOAAUuYQgB4AFQUcVgA+M1xhDQASZBQZAHkJVVcAQSgoFFcggB8ccTUlbV0UfTDhVlFxKXhApGlIoJDwgAocFFYFHwg-ILCASjMI4TgxuH8ZYAA3CvH5joA6EBQwVtH5zbhWsF9CIdMI3d7CRcLVOAB+XnPeOCVeCBgACyQoES2xgar5-wB6KazaqSRoAd0irQOETwAhg+CgEgm9UaKFMODk5FyuUs1g09BQqmITnYfwirCAA)

Comment: Yes this is the correct answer. With flow, I'd recommend always defaulting to using read-only and exact types as much as possible, then only use mutable types for data types that actually _need_ to be mutable. Otherwise, you'll run into lots of subtle errors like this one, and spend a bunch of time trying to track them down. Everything with flow makes way more sense and is easier to reason about with exact and read-only types.

Comment: I also came to the same conclusion! Now it is just a matter of convince my coworkers

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant:

```
type Props<T:{}> = {
  a: Array<{cool: boolean}> | Array<T>
}
```

[Try flow](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxLZFICiAZvUhnAL5z1QQhwDkUqDLwBQwtBAB2heABMKKAFy4QEADaK4AIwhrUE1gG0AunAC8cAzhXqlMKPiSsjomAE8wSOAAUuYQgB4AFQUcVgA+M1xhDQBBKCgUV38ccTUlbV0UfQiAHzg4hKTAsOFWUXEpeECkaUigkPCAChwUVgUfCD8gsIBKMwjhOCG4fxlgADcS4emWgDoQFDBGwenVuEawX0I+0wjNzsJZ1NU4AH5eY944JV4IGAALJCgRNaGesun-AHoxyfLJWoAd0ijR2ETwAhg+CgEhG1VqKFMODk5ByOUs1g09BQqmITnYXwirCAA)

Comment: Yeah, that works, but I'm curious now too, why `Array<T | {cool: boolean}>` not working.

Comment: That will require the array to have one type or the other, not an array fo two types. But if it makes flow shut up, I'll give it a try

Comment: Why you think having `Array<{} | {cool: boolean}>` is an array of two types? It results in `Array<{}>`

Comment: That will work to make it accept the values I'm passing, but inside, as soon as I try to access the T conditionally it will fail: https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxLZFICiAZvUhnAL5z1QQhwDkUqDLwBQwmAE8wSOABUAFsAB2AczgBeXCAgAbFAC44AIwg7Ui1qLQRFheABMK+2QpUBtALrq4rnFt0GYKHwkVkxfHSd6FG1iVndRCSk4AAUuMEIAHhk9HFYAPi8cYScZDwAfHCsdA2NTFHMPTGE0QwMACgAPPRkASnUC+vFhC2brW1kkcY0snPy2nBRsFtY9VIh0rLy+tQLhOH24DLtgADc8vYODhYA6EBQwNovL587tgo7rqu04AH5eL94cAMLVeT2ePQslwyAHpjmdLGN4C0vJ1ui5lG84B1RjZ4AB3FGYvACGD4KCKQ4ySbwFBqHAOchlMo+PyRaKxMJfAJBELudgtOnLODQgqsIA

Comment: Ok, I thing the key part is described in this other issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44155934/flowtype-array-of-object-type-does-not-allow-extra-properties